# 'No such file or directory' error on Filereader - Android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to import a CSV in my SQLite database on Android, using an intent to have the user choose the CSV file.

I get an ENOENT error on : `FileReader file = new FileReader(fileName);`

The file does exist since I get the path form an intent !

**My manifest** includes :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**My intent** :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("text/csv");
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CVS);
```

**My onActivityResult(...)** :

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
   File myPath_CSV = new  File(data.getData().toString());
   try {
       myDb.importCSV(myPath_CSV);
   } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

**My importCSV(fileName)** :

```
public void importOreilles(File fileName) throws IOException {
    Log.w(TAG, fileName.toString());
    FileReader file = new FileReader(fileName);   // Getting an error !!!
    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(file);

    String line = null;
    while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] str = line.split(",");
        insertOreille(str[0],str[1]);  // Dealing with my database
    }
}
```

**The error I'm getting** :

```
W/DBAdapter: file:/storage/emulated/0/Download/Oreilles.csv
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /file:/storage/emulated/0/Download/ABCDE.csv: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

I tried using getAbsolutePath, Uri, File... but I'm stuck.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The file does exist since I get the path form an intent !

You decided not to provide the actual "intent" and how you use it. I am going to guess that it is `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`. In that case, you get back a `Uri` (`data.getData()`). [Use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/15/how-consume-content-uri.html) to read in the contents pointed to by that `Uri`. You can wrap that in an `InputStreamReader` to use with your existing `Reader`-based code.

Comment: Just added My intent (Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT indeed)

Comment: @Tibo: The `Uri` that you get back could have either a `file` or a `content` scheme. `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` will handle both cases, assuming that, in the case of a `file`, [the user granted you permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635704/android-permission-doesnt-work-even-if-i-have-declared-it).

Comment: From your link, I think my problem is my lack of understanding of what is a Uri. I'm gonna have a look on openInputStream.

Comment: I'm still lost. Suppose i use `InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri_CSV)`. How am I supposed to use the `is` to read the lines of the CSV file ?

Comment: @Tibo: As I wrote in my answer, you can wrap that in an `InputStreamReader` for use with your existing CSV code. Or, use a CSV library.

Comment: Thanks. I got it working with `InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(inStream);` and `BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(isr);`